# How to set worksheet name = name returned by function call

Tags: excel, vba

This code compiles but does not work:

```
Dim wsLabel As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

wsLabel = paramToWriteWorksheet(paramLabel)
Set ws = Sheets("wsLabel")
```

where paramToWriteWorksheet returns a string that is the name of an existing worksheet

How can I get the code to do what my title says?

Comment: Remove the quotes. Edit: maybe not... you might have to concatenate quotes with the variable XD

Comment: tried that. no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Sub qwerty()
   Dim wsLabel As String
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = ActiveSheet

   wsLabel = paramToWriteWorksheet(paramLabel)
   ws.Name = wsLabel
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried your code. Now the main function triggers a circular reference warning, requiring user to click on [OK], and then the main function evaluates to 0, which is not the correct answer, presumably because it is not pointing to the intended worksheet.

Comment: @Max  **You must put a value in `paramLabel` when you adapt this code.

Comment: I do: paramLabel is a string that is passed to the function paramToWriteWorksheet, which returns another string, which is the name of the worksheet that is to be used in the main function.